# why the interactive mode of my gnuplot installation won't rotate when it will for batch.dem files and also for Octave

Tags: input, mouse, rotation, gnuplot, interactive

I have gnuplot 4.6 working on Mac OS X.  It works from Octave as well.  This isn't an octave related question, just trying to convince you that gnuplot seems to be installed fine.  My problem is that while I CAN rotate plots with the mouse (am using x11 as the plotting window) in a batch sort of mode (e.g.   $unixPrompt> gnuplot pm3d.dem  works fine: I can rotate/zoom them), and ALSO can rotate 3d plots created from within Octave,  but I CANNOT just go into gnuplot  and rotate any such plot from the interactive gnuplot program.
ie.  gnuplot> issuePlotCommands…    will put up the plot just fine, but I cannot then rotate that plot like I can do when I've issued the same commands in a batch or Octave-driven manner.  My interactive gnuplot seems to allow no mouse input whatsoever.   I currently have GNUTERM=x11 in my  .profile. Can anyone point out why the interactive mode of my gnuplot installation won't rotate when it will for batch.dem fils and also for Octave? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

does adding `set mouse` make any difference?

(from the gnuplot doc)

```
The command `set mouse` enables mouse actions. Currently the pm, x11, ggi,
windows and wxt terminals are mouse enhanced. There are two mouse modes. The
2d-graph mode works for 2d graphs and for maps (i.e. splots with `set view`
having z-rotation 0, 90, 180, 270 or 360 degrees, including `set view map`)
and it allows tracing the position over graph, zooming, annotating graph etc.
For 3d graphs `splot`, the view and scaling of the graph can be changed with
mouse buttons 1 and 2. If additionally to these buttons the modifier <ctrl> is
hold down, the coordinate system only is rotated which is useful for large
data sets. A vertical motion of Button 2 with the shift key hold down changes
the `xyplane`.
```

Notice that the following will work:

```
echo "plot sin(x); pause mouse keypress" | gnuplot -persist
```

but this won't:

```
echo "plot sin(x)" | gnuplot -persist
```

since the gnuplot process must be alive for the gnuplot_x11 driver to talk to for the rotating.

Comment: It's interesting... the "set mouse" didn't do anything (and I had tried a few set mouse variations), but the addition of "pause mouse keypress" within the gnuplot.. ie:
    gnuplot> splot sin(blahblah); pause mouse keypress;   
worked.  I can now rotate the plot as I wanted.  So thank you.  
With regard to your comments about the gnuplot process needing to be alive (which makes sense), I looked at the ps command output, and noticed that the gnuplot and gnuplot_x11 were persistent across interactive commands.  Perhaps the "pause mouse keypress" says to look for mouse commands?

Comment: A little clarity on the ps command:  I looked at ps both when I entered 
   a) gnuplot> splot sin(blah);    
   b) gnuplot> splot sin(blah); pause mouse keypress;
and the gnuplot (of course, it is the interactive program) and gnuplot_x11 were present (and unchanging in the process id's) across 
both variations.  for what its worth.

Comment: @werdevo -- `pause mouse keypress` does say to look for keyboard/mouse input, but I don't see why that would really make a difference if you're sitting there typing away at the gnuplot prompt ... (It doesn't make a difference for me).

Comment: @mgilson- hmm, I play around some more: it seems that "pause mouse keypress" looks for mouse input until some keypress... right? It seems that, when in interactive mode my (I have a mac mini) "option" key turns off (ie ends the mouseinput stream) the mouse, and in fact, I have to restart gnuplot to negate this effect. This is extra strange to me because when I'm in batch mode, running (say) the pm3d.dem demo, my option key serves to enhance the mouse input to the plotting window, ie the "option" key will scale the vertical axis and/or zoom, depending on my mouse trajectory. !!??

Answer (score 10):

Type in `pause -1`.  That enabled rotation for me!