# No gnuplot wxt terminal in kubuntu 15.04, plasma 5

Tags: gnuplot, kde-plasma, ubuntu-15.04

The `wxt` terminal is not listed in `gnuplot`. The `x11` and `qt` terminals are listed and work but for some reason *aren't interactive*. I tried reinstalling both `gnuplot-x11` and `gnuplot5-x11` normally through `sudo apt-get install` after removing the existing install with `sudo apt-get remove`, but in vain.

Any ideas? Cheers /J

**Edit**: In fact, the `qt` and `x11` terminals are interactive when called from within gnuplot with `load 'commands.gp'`, but not from the bash using `gnuplot -p -e "load 'commands.gp'"`. That's a problem as I use aliases and scripts to plot files and need the interactive terminal to evaluate them.

**Edit 2**: I get the message

```
kf5.kiconthemes: "Theme tree: (Breeze)"
```

when trying to plot from the command line, and no interactivity.

I installed Gnome 3. There the interactivity works as expected.

Comment: Try the suggestion given in http://stackoverflow.com/a/10457261/2604213, i.e. echo the command to gnuplot

Comment: I tried piping with and without the suggested `pause` commands, but it didn't make any difference at all.